# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5432 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to connect to PostreSQL database. I am working with JavaScript, TypeScript, NestJS and TypeORM. I have the database created in pgAdmin 4.

Everything was working until I changed some code that has to do with functionality of the app and not the server. The code that I added is also valid and shouldn't cause problems. In app.module.ts I have this code for TypeOrmModule:

```
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: 'my_password',
      database: 'database_name',
      entities: [NewsEntity],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
```

This is what the console looks like:

```
[Nest] 55824  - 08.03.2023, 13:08:04   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
```

I am running Windows 11, running the app with Nodemon and using PostgreSQL 14. Also here are the versions (that might have something to do with the error) that I have installed:

```json
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
"rxjs": "^7.8.0",
"typeorm": "^0.3.12",
"@types/node": "18.11.18",
```

I was expecting a regular server start with connection to database established like it was before. I tried connecting to the server from pgAdmin 4 but it throws the same error and refuses to connect. Please help

Comment: It seems, your postgres service is not alive, check its status by using the terminal command pg_lscluster. your postgres service might have been down, or else that provided config port might have wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a Node.js Github issue about it](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40702)

tl;dr: hosts lookup algorithm changed between Node 16 and Node 17.

But it was [fixed in Node.js v20](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/44731), so if you can, just update to v20, if you can't then just use **direct 127.0.0.1 IP** as other answer suggested. In any case, **don't remove** `::1         localhost` from the hosts!

Comment: I spent good 5 hours trying to figure out what the problem was...all I needed to do was to upgrade node to v20, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have two entries in your **hosts** file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost
```

The first is for IPv4 and second is for IPv6 protocol. In your case, the app is trying to connect to ::1.

Just use the explicit IP **127.0.0.1** instead of **localhost** in your configuration.